# Private chatroom for trusted users?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Recently there has been a big drive to clean up the quality of the site by removing obsolete, low quality, off topic, and unanswerable questions. This has largely been down to the efforts a couple of users and driven through active use of the chat room. However, I think it is a bit difficult to discuss these sorts of issues on a publicly visible chat, partly because it can result in the user of interest joining in and taking the discussion off topic.

Would it be a good idea for trusted users to have access to a completely private chat room? That way we could discuss issues such as users who repeatedly ignore the policies of the site etc. without the risk of being subject to personal attack from these (often very rude) users

However it does feel a little bit [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) allowing the a small minority to back channel and it makes me feel uneasy! Seeking opinions :)

Comment: I don't think it is a very good idea. Closing questions and cleaning up relies on the consense of the community (we need 5 votes for every closure) and shouldn't be done by only a small group. I don't agree with each close vote (as other don't do this with mine), this prevents the overturning of the community by a few users.

Comment: @Chris Agreed, just feel like we need to have a forum where we can discuss the issues around specific posts without the possibility of harassment from users that do not understand, appreciate, or accept the possibility that those posts are flawed. Perhaps I am just getting weary and disillusioned...

Comment: I guess this is why there are reasons to close vote, we can see what other users have voted for and see if we agree - but sometimes I feel I need to better explain my reasoning

Comment: Better explanations will only help, if the users in question do read and understand these comments. Which is sometimes questionable.

Comment: @Chris when in doubt, always refer back to the appropriate page of the help center. It's up to the posters to read the comments and take them to heart, but if you feel uncomfortable just leaving a comment saying *This question is off-topic because of XYZ*, throw in a link to the Help Center so they can read more (if they so choose).

Comment: Depends on the history of the user. But I could really add a link to the help center. Good idea. Others will not understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Private chat rooms are reserved for moderation purposes, they are only meant for stuff diamond moderators can't talk about in public. While we have the ability to create private rooms and give regular users access, SE has told us moderators that private rooms for anything but actual moderation purposes are not allowed.

A room like this would violate that rule and won't be allowed. In general it is a good idea to keep most of the discussions about moderation in public.